# How to exclude row if field exists in another table? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am having trouble excluding a row in a query if a certain field in that row exists in another table.

For example,

`SELECT column1, column2`

`FROM Table1`

And let's say it results out to

```
**column1**      **column2**
   Name1            Name2
```

Then in Table2, there is also a column1 and it has Name1 value as well.

How would I edit my first query to check Table2 and if it has Name1 under column1 as well, then exclude the whole row?

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 6):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.column1 = t1.column1
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using `not in` is pretty simple and readable

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2 FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.column1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.column1 FROM Table2 t2)
```

Comment: Although using `not exists` as @gordon-linoff suggested performs better when there are `NULL` values in the column.